# Sync Framework create Template

Tags: c#, sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm using sync FX in my application. There is 1 Main database and multiple client databases linked to it.
I have created a template with filtering in Main server.

Do I have to create templates in clients databases separately, or can I use the template created in Main server to create scope?

I couldn't find a proper tutorial regarding Creating Templates in server and client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the scopes deriving from a template must reside on the same database where the template is defined. If you have defined a template in the server, you can create the corresponding scopes for each client in the server side.

On the client side, you will have to define the corresponding scope for every client scope you defined in the server.